# The results are different ; recv(sock,buf,sizeof(buf),0) and strlen(buf) in c++

Tags: c++

This is my code..

```
char buf[5000];
bool isHandshaking = false;
bool isSingaling = false;

while(1)
{
    //-----------클라이언트로부터 수신------------

    int recvsize = recv(sock,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
    printf("recvsize = %d\n",recvsize);

    buf[recvsize] = '\0';
    printf("buf_len = %d\n",strlen(buf));
    .
    .
    .
}
```

The above result...

```
recvsize = 2525
buf_len = 126 /*(or different value, sometimes 2525)*/
```

value of recvsize is alaways 2525
And I expected that the strlen value of buf would of course be equal to recvsize.However, bufsize is sometimes equal to 2525 ,But sometimes it is not the same.
What am I missing?

Comment: Did you know that [std::strlen](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) counts up to the first `'\0'` it finds?

Comment: What @Galik is saying is that `recvsize` is the number of bytes received on the socket. However a string is an array of characters and the array of bytes now assumes string semantics and not byte array semantics when passed to `strlen()`. So `strlen()` returns the number of characters found from the starting point to when an end of string or value of zero is found. To determine if this is indeed what is happening you can check to see if the character after the length returned by `strlen()` is a zero or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should recv() result must be equal to buffer length?](/q/17224500/90527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means there is a null byte in the received data (which means you likely shouldn't be treating it as textual data to begin with, it is clearly binary data instead).  `recv()` received 2525 bytes, but the byte located at index 126 was `0x00`. `strlen()` stops counting at the first `'\0'` char it encounters.

You also have a potential buffer overflow. If `recv()` happens to receive exactly `sizeof(buf)` number of bytes, you are writing a NULL terminator out of bounds of your array.  You would need to request `sizeof(buf)-1` bytes instead. Otherwise, don't insert a NULL terminator into `buf` at all. Dont treat it as null-terminated text, since it is technically arbitrary data, and do use the value returned by `recv()` to know how many bytes `buf` actually holds.